# Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\log (n+1)}$ by using expansion of $\log (n+1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{n}{\log (n+1)}$ by using expansion of $\log (n+1)$.

By using L' hospital,

Value of this limit is $\lim_{n \to \infty} = n+1 = \infty$

By expansion of $\log$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n-n^{2}/2 + n^{3}/3 \dots }$

How will I get $\infty$ from this?

Comment: I don't think that expansion of $\log$ works for $n$ large

Comment: I presume you want $n\in\mathbb{R}$ instead of natural numbers. Otherwise, L'Hopital and Taylor Series Expansion will not make sense. (Of course you can find some literature to see that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x) = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(n)$ but I will not discuss it here).

Now, you have to ensure the radius of convergence of $\log{(1+n)}$ here makes sense. Your series has radius of convergence 1 which means it is valid only for $|n|<1$.
You should try different way to expand the series first.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\frac{n}{\log (n+1)}=\frac{n}{\log (n)+\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}=\frac{n}{\log (n)+\left( \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)\right)}\sim \frac{n}{\log (n)}$$